# Data entry for power bi report without additional direct query database

Tags: sharepoint, powerbi, powerapps

Goal:

Integrate power apps with power bi (vica verse) without setting up a SQL database for direct query to allow data input of internal tables to power bi report.

The database we are reading from cannot be used for data entry purposes.

E.g. there is a business process whereby a client must track the location of each asset. This is done by creating a table of a distinct id of each asset and then a data entry drop down is applied so users can update the location of each asset which is updated in the report visuals.

Resources:

https://www.google.com/search?q=integrate+power+bi+and+power+apps+direct+quert&oq=integrate+power+bi...

https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Filtering-data-in-PowerApps-based-on-Power-B...

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/powerapps-custom-visual

Solution attempt 1: creating a  sharepoint list to store user entry results. An app was created and embedded within PowerBI, however the power bi report did filter results to the app. Likewise results were not immediately shown in the PowerBi report. SharePoint does not have a direct query function, and is limited to 8 refreshes a day + it could not be refreshed through the web browser, only by scheduled refreshes.

Attempted solution 2: using internal PowerBI datasets. Accessing the data from PowerBI datasets inside of powerapps seemed to be read only. Is this the case?

Question for the forum: how do you create data entry for a powerbi report without setting up another database to store results.

Comment: You can't. Power BI is not a database, you will need a database to store results and they display them.

Comment: Keep in mind that non-delegable data sources have a hard 2000 row limit (i.e. Sharepoint, Excel online, etc.). SQL or some other database (common data service, Azure Data Lake, etc.) is the only logical answer.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/delegation-overview